# Microsoft Graph: How to get the favorited Groups of the current user?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

How can I get a list of Office Groups favorited by the current user?

Groups have a [(non-default) property `isFavorite`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_get#default-properties) but it seems it can't be used for filtering. So this endpoint does **not** work:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups?$filter=isFavorite eq true`

Here is the response from [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer):
[image]

Is there another way to get the favorite Groups of the current user?

Answer (score 0):

Hello @Heinrich Ulbricht.
Editing my previous answer as there IS a way to get a list of favorite groups for the current user with:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/joinedGroups?$filter=isFavorite eq true
```

Comment: Sounds promising. But two things: this doesn't cover public groups I'm following but are no member of, right? And I tested favoriting a group - the API still returns `isFavorite==false`. Did you test that on your end? Does it work? Maybe it takes time to return a changed `isFavorite` state via API. Or it's just broken.

Comment: `joinedGroups` shows only the groups the user is a member of. I did test it on my end and it does take a while (a couple of minutes or less) for the change to be properly returned by the API, just like with everything else. I'm afraid this is the only way to, currently, return groups with the `isFavorite` attribute.